# I can't create a decimal number correctly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to create an input where you can write a number with decimals.
I don't know how to make it so that a user cant insert two points characters.

**Example**
I want to prevent the user from writing `0.123445.5`, only with one point: `0.123445`

I have tried with ionic input properties like `step="0.01"` but I can't solve it.

**EDIT: (SOLVED)**

Instead using number, use `type="string"` and create a method to check number of points of the number.

Before:

```
<ion-item">
  <ion-label stacked>CRP</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="CRP" (ngModelChange)="checkRules();"
   onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57"> </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Now:

```
<ion-item">
  <ion-label stacked>CRP</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="CRP" (ngModelChange)="checkCRPkDecimals();"
   onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57"> </ion-input>
</ion-item>


checkCRPkDecimals() {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.CRP))) return;

  let str:Array<string> = this.CRP.split(".");
  if (str.length > 2) {
    this.CRP = "";
    return;
  } else {
    this.checkRules();
  }
}
```

Comment: Code of `checkRule()`?

Comment: is a method that I call

Comment: Can you show the `code` of it?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it. I thought that I was doing it correctly. Next time I'll post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Why not this time?